# Sort json list of numbers when there is a string present

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have html form that accepts parameters and then a python app (flask) that sorts a json file before returning the results. This works fine except for the few entries where the Price is not numerical but a string (specifically "Call for Price").

```
        sortparam=request.form["inputsearch"]
        if sortparam == 'Location':
            keyparam = lambda s: s['Location']
        elif sortparam == 'Price':
            keyparam = lambda s: int(s['Price'].replace(',', ''))
        elif sortparam == 'Size':
            keyparam = lambda s: s['Size']
```

```
    with open("output/boatlist.json", "r") as jdata:
        data = json.load(jdata)
        data['boats'].sort(key=keyparam)
```

Here is a sample of the json:

```
    "boats": [
        {
            "Name": "Lagoon 46",
            "Price": "Call For Price",
            "Size": "46 ft / 2020",
            "Location": "Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Lagoon 42",
            "Price": "790,000",
            "Size": "42 ft / 2021",
            "Location": "Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Leopard 40",
            "Price": "560,000",
            "Size": "40 ft / 2016",
            "Location": "Victoria, British Columbia, Canada"
        }
   ]
```

At this point I have solved it by just replacing all "Call For Pricing" with "0" when building the json but I was wondering if there was an elegant way of sorting them to the end of the list.

Comment: If "Call For Price' is changed to 0, this will be at the start of your list rather than the end, won't it? Is this what you want?

Comment: No. I'd rather have it at the end, but with a zero at least it runs.

Comment: Ok, check my updated answer and use the variant with `float('inf')`, that should give you what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just extend your keyparam function to add a case for "Call For Price" like this:

```
keyparam = lambda s: 0 if s['Price'].lower() == "call for price" else int(s['Price'].replace(',', ''))
```

Using 0 here, as that's what you mentioned in your question. However, if you prefer for it to be at the end of the list, you can use `float('inf')` instead:

```
keyparam = lambda s: float('inf') if s['Price'].lower() == "call for price" else int(s['Price'].replace(',', ''))
```

It's questionable whether this is elegant or not, but it solves the problem without having to modify the data directly

**Edit**: I updated this to use `.lower()` on the string in case, like in your example, the casing of the string is not always capitalized words

Comment: I tried something like that but got this error (which I also get for your function) "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Call for Price'"

Comment: @macblaze really? This ran just fine for me

Comment: @macblaze ah wait I assumed that the casing would always be exactly "Call For Price". See my updated answer

Comment: It was the capital F in "For". But your second version works infinitely better. Thanks.

Comment: @macblaze no problem and yeah I just noticed that you said "Call for Price" at the top of your post, but I saw the "Call For Price" in your code snippet so I went with that

Answer (score 0):

Setting the field to 0 when building the JSON might be the most efficient way, but arguably not the most elegant and explicit way of doing it.

You can define a function to use as the key as follows:

```
...
elif sortparam == 'Price':
    def keyparam (s):
        text = s['Price'].replace(',', '')
        try:
            return int(text)
        except ValueError as e:
            return 0
...
```

Or if you want to stick with lambdas:

```
elif sortparam == 'Price':
    keyparams = lambda s: int(s['Price'].replace(',', '')) if s['Price'].replace(',', '').replace('-', '').isdigit() else 0
```

Or if you know there's exactly only one value that is not a number:

```
elif sortparam == 'Price':
    keyparams = lambda s: 0 if s['Price'] == 'Call for Price' else int(s['Price'].replace(',', ''))
```

Comment: In the second example, (which works great as well btw) I am confused what the replace('-', '') is for.

Comment: `str.isdigit()`  only works for strings with numerals. If your string is negative, `str.isdigit()` will return `False`. If you know these values will always be positive (or a text) since they're prices, you can skip `.replace('-', '')`

Comment: If the answer helped, even if not accepted, an upvote would be appreciated :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers